# Размещении двух объектов в строку в LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-button, android-linearlayout

Как я могу разместить два ImageButton в одну строку в LinearLayout? Я бы использовал RelativeLayout, но в RelativeLayout объекты не размещаются в один столбик. Если и использовать RelativeLayout, то я не знаю, как сделать так, чтобы объекты в relativeLayout размешались в один столбик.
Код:

```
private void potatoFunc() {  
    LinearLayout mainLayout = findViewById(R.id.mainmain);
    final ImageButton imageView = new ImageButton(Main2Activity.this);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams imageViewLayoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(450, 150);

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams imageParamsDeleteBtn = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(50, 75);
    final ImageButton deleteButton = new ImageButton(Main2Activity.this);
    deleteButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.delete);
    deleteButton.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
    deleteButton.setLayoutParams(imageParamsDeleteBtn);
    deleteButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    imageParamsDeleteBtn.setMargins(50,40,0,0);
    mainLayout.addView(deleteButton);

    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.product);
    imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
    imageView.setLayoutParams(imageViewLayoutParams);
    imageView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    imageViewLayoutParams.setMargins(15,10,0,0);
    mainLayout.addView(imageView);



    SharedPreferences sharedPref = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
    editor.putInt("int", 25);
    editor.apply();



}



private void ogyrecFunc() {
    LinearLayout mainLayout = findViewById(R.id.mainmain);
    final ImageButton imageView1 = new ImageButton(Main2Activity.this);
    imageView1.setImageResource(R.drawable.ogyrecproduct);
    imageView1.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams imageViewLayoutParams1 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(450,150);
    imageView1.setLayoutParams(imageViewLayoutParams1);
    imageView1.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    imageViewLayoutParams1.setMargins(15,10,0,0);


    LinearLayout.LayoutParams imageParamsDeleteBtn = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(50, 75);
    final ImageButton deleteButton = new ImageButton(Main2Activity.this);
    deleteButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.delete);
    deleteButton.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
    deleteButton.setLayoutParams(imageParamsDeleteBtn);
    deleteButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    imageParamsDeleteBtn.setMargins(50,40,0,0);
    mainLayout.addView(deleteButton);


    SharedPreferences sharedPref = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
    editor.putInt("int", 26);
    editor.apply();




    mainLayout.addView(imageView1);

}
```

Comment: Всего два, или в два столбца?

Comment: @woesss Есть две кнопки в столбик. К каждой кнопки в строке прибавляется ещё одна кнопка.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если надо в строку, то выбираешь параметр

```
android:orientation="horizontal"
```

Если надо в столбик, то задаешь "vertical". В общем должно получиться как то так:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
      android:orientation="vertical"
      tools:context=".MainActivity">

 <LinerLayout
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:layout_weight="1"
     android:orientation="horizontal">

      <ImageButton
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_gravity="center"
         android:layout_weight="1"/>

      <ImageButton
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_gravity="center"
         android:layout_weight="1"/>
     </LinearLayout>

    <LinerLayout
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:layout_weight="1"
     android:orientation="horizontal">

      <ImageButton
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_gravity="center"
         android:layout_weight="1"/>

      <ImageButton
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_gravity="center"
         android:layout_weight="1"/>
     </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Мне надо, чтобы было 2 кнопки в столбик, и в каждой строке ещё по две кнопки. Всего 4 кнопки. Надо использовать LinearLayout

Comment: Тогда в Вертикальный контейнер вставляем два горизонтальных. Можно наоборот. Выше поправил.

Comment: У меня кнопки создаются динамически, отредактирую свой вопрос, вставлю туда код, как они добавляются.

Comment: Добавил код, посмотрите

Comment: Ну что? Я пока ничего не придумал. Или вторые кнопки создавать в другом LinearLayout?

Comment: Все то что я написал, можно сделать и java кодом. Но по моему слишком у вас код перегруженный. Если разметка меняется динамически, то по моему проще поиграться с фрагментами.

Comment: Да, согласен с вами. Можете сказать, как пользоваться фрагментами? Я бы хотел перенести наш диалог в чат

Comment: Дайте мыло, я свои учебные заметки по фрагментам скину. Ну и на вопросы отвечу. Если что советую пройтись по https://devcolibri.com/android-fragment-%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BE/ еще https://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/174-urok-104-android-3-fragments-lifecycle.html и http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/theory/fragments.php Последний мне больше всего нравится.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84093/discussion-between--and-).